# System Idle Process network traffic?-Updated

Tags: windows-7, network-traffic

I was using NetBalancer and noticed network traffic on an unidentified service, but when I highlight it and then go to the lower center pane and click the parent process it says it is the System Idle process, it is showing incoming and outgoing traffic in the upper pane, anyone know why this Windows System Idle Process is talking on the network?

Windows 7 HP 64bit

.
[image]

.
[image]

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After blocking the traffic for that unidentified Service I checked my event viewer (Windows Logs>System) and found 3 new events that were never recorded before and matched the time I blocked the traffic.

.

> Event ID 1014 DNS Client Events
>
> Name resolution for the name dns.msftncsi.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
>
> [dns.msftncsi.com](http://www.robtex.com/dns/msftncsi.com.html)
>
> Name resolution for the name wpad.home timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
>
> [wpad](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271361)
>
> Name resolution for the name mscrl.microsoft.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
>
> [mscrl.microsoft.com](http://www.robtex.com/dns/mscrl.microsoft.com.html)

.

Then My Web Browser refused to work, I re-enabled the traffic and all returned to normal. Case closed.

[image]